# LFTP fails on fast changing directories

Tags: ftp, debian, mirror, lftp

LFTP 4.9.2 (Libraries used: Expat 2.2.6, Readline 7.0, zlib 1.2.11)

I'm trying to mirror a website with a fast changing cache directory. LFTP always fails with:
`mirror: Access failed: 550 Can't change directory to cache-60cc55190313f589631026-tmp: No such file or directory (/web/wp-content/cache/comet-cache/cache-60cc55190313f589631026-tmp)`

Already disabled cache, tried skip-noaccess. Nothing helps. Can someone advice?

```
lftp -u username,pass IP -p 21 -d -e 'set log:enabled yes; 
set log:file "lftp.log"; 
set cache:enable no; 
set cmd:verify-path-cached yes; 
set mirror:parallel-directories no; 
set ftp:ssl-allow no; 
set ssl:verify-certificate no; 
set ssl:check-hostname no; 
set ftp:prefer-epsv false; 
set ftp:list-options -a; 
set net:timeout 15; 
set net:max-retries 10; 
set net:reconnect-interval-base 5; 
set log:prefix-error "LFTP_ERROR"; 
set log:prefix-note "LFTP_NOTE"; 
set xfer:log 1; 
set xfer:log-file "transfer.log"; 
set ftps:initial-prot "P"; 
set ftp:passive-mode true; 
set -a; 
mirror --skip-noaccess --parallel=7 /dir/ /download; 
bye' 2>&1
```

There is nothing in global config file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Simply exchange the two folders.
Before: `mirror --skip-noaccess --parallel=7 /dir/ /download;`
After:   `mirror --skip-noaccess --parallel=7 /download /dir ;`

Comment: May be this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70058912/9134997